# Why is Sierpinski's Gasket connected?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

I have been studying some basics of IFSs and their attractors. Sierpinski's Gasket is the attractor of a linear IFS in $\mathbb {R}^2$. One important property is that it is connected. I couldn't prove it, then I did some research and got to his original article in \italic{Comptes Rendus}, but I couldn't find any other way to prove such fact besides the one he presents in his article. Could you give me some reference, please?

Answer (score 0):

[Sierpinski's gasket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle#/media/File:Sierpinski_triangle.svg) is the closure of the union of a countable collection of triangles $C_1,C_2,C_3,...$ having the property that for each $n$ the triangle $C_n$ has nonempty intersection with (at least one of) the previous triangles $C_1,C_2,...,C_{n-1}$. Here when I refer to a "triangle" I mean not a solid triangle, but instead just the union of its three sides, which is clearly connected.

It follows by induction that the union of the first $n$ terms $G_n = C_1 \cup C_2 \cup ... \cup C_n$ is connected. Since $G_1 \subset G_2 \subset \cdots$ is a nested sequence of connected sets, it follows that the full union $\cup_{n=1}^\infty G_n = \cup_{n-1}^\infty C_n$ is connected. Since the closure of a connected set is connected it follows that Sierpinski's gasket is connected.